# How to list all request parameters in springboot webservice?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, spring-boot

I am trying to convert my application from spring to springboot, I have a problem in a web service parameter in springboot application.

This is my spring application:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/personels")
    public Response getAllPersonels(@Context HttpHeaders headers, @Context Request request) {

    String url = String.valueOf(((ContainerRequest) request).getRequestUri());
    System.out.println(url);

    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(new Personel()).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).build();
   }
```

this is also my springboot application:

```
@RequestMapping("/personels")
public Response saveWebService(@Context HttpHeaders headers, @Context Request request) {

  String url = String.valueOf(((ContainerRequest) request).getRequestUri());
  System.out.println(url);

  return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(new Personel()).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}
```

here is springboot error

```
{
    "timestamp": 1500382494978,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException",
    "message": "Failed to instantiate [javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders]: Specified class is an interface",
    "path": "/personels/"
}
```

These are just sample, but in the future I am going to use all request parameter(method,headers, entity,type..)

Is there an annotation for this problem?

Comment: You are mixing Spring MVC and Jax-RS. `@Path` and `@Context` have nothing to do with Spring, those are JAX-RS annotations.

Comment: You can inject `HttpServletRequest` instead of `Request` and get headers from that

Comment: is there an annotation for this problem? I just want to get all fields a web request

Comment: With `HttpServletRequest` you have access to the complete request. You don't need an annotation for that, just add it as method parameter and you get the object (but only after you cleaned up your project, of course)

Comment: thank you, I changed my code. And now works successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is about Jax-RS and spring mvc mixing. I noticed it thanks to @M. Deinum and @Viswanath Lekshmanan

finally I've changed method parameters like that;

```
@RequestMapping("/virtual")
public Response saveWebService(HttpServletRequest request){

}
```